# Campo Vacio Datatable visual basic window form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms

Buenas Tardes una consulta estoy realizando en window form una aplicacion que me extraiga cuando ingreso el nombre de un campo pero ese campo aun esta vacio el campo pero cuando ejecuto me salta un error de esto :
**el campo esta vacio pero en el row sale como 1 y entra a la condicion pero como es null sale ese error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi codigo es el siguiente :**

```
 dt = New DataTable
            dt = vB_Atencion.MostrarUsuarioIncidencia(2, TxtTicket.Text, CboAsignar.Text).Tables(0)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                lblUsuarioAsignado.Text = dt.Rows(0)("AsignarA")

            End If
```

Comment: Pierro hay algo que me produce inquietud el código que colocaste tiene la sentencia "dt = New Datatable" y la verdad eso no me suena a VB6, como la etiqueta que colocaste. ¿En qué Visual estas trabajando? ¿Visual Studio? Corrigelo asi la pregunta queda correctamente.

Comment: @AgustinM. le corregia exactamente lo mismo en el chat ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **problema** que te sucede es que quieres asignar a una propiedad **String** (que es lblUsuarioAsignado.Text) un valor que es leído como **DBNull**, por eso el error.

Para salvar resto tienes dos opciones:

La primera es convertir el objeto en cuestion en una String, con el método .ToString

```
lblUsuarioAsignado.Text = dt.Rows(0)("AsignarA").ToString
```

La segunda opción es salvar el hecho de que ese objeto puede ser **DBNull**, y eso se puede hacer con la comprobación **IsDBNull(*objeto*)**

```
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
 If IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0)("AsignarA")) = False then
   lblUsuarioAsignado.Text = dt.Rows(0)("AsignarA")
 Else
   lblUsuarioAsignado.Text = ""
 End If
End If
```

Comment: agregaria un else lblUsuarioAsignado.Text = "".. no vaya a ser que tenga datos de antes y quede lleno sin querer

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi , tenido en cuenta la ayuda !!

Comment: @gbianchi  muchas gracias si me soluciono son excelente muchas gracias. :D

Comment: @AgustinM. muchas graciass............ :D